# Parental filter which blocks Tarot and other Black magic

Tags: software-recommendation, parental-controls

I am searching for a closed source or open source (MacPorts) internet filtering which blocks Black magic (for example Tarot) web sites.

Very important that this also works with Russian language ([example Google query](https://www.google.com/search?q=gadanie%20online))

Background info: my customer is a Catholic single mom.

Answer (score 1):

In my home, we use a combination of:

1. OpenDNS filtering.
2. Locking down the devices so that the end user cannot change the Internet settings, specifically DNS.
3. The [Mobicip](http://www.mobicip.com) browser, which has a free version, but for advanced features such as specific site filtering, costs $9.99 annually.

I don't specifically filter Black Magic, but there are other things I do block, and these tools allow me to have control over what gets into my network via the Internet.